# Smart contract returning values as zeros

Tags: arrays, mapping, struct

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract TransManager {
  //state variables

  // contract owner
  address private creator;

  uint transCounter;

  // File Meta metaData
  struct metaData{
    uint id;
    address owner;
    string docType;
    string fileHash;
  }

  //Array to store tranasactions
  mapping (address => metaData[])  fileLogs;


  //Send a trnsactionId

  function regTransaction(string _docType, string _fileHash) public {
    transCounter++;
    var fileLog = metaData(transCounter, msg.sender, _docType, _fileHash );

    fileLogs[msg.sender].push(fileLog);

  }

  function getTransactions() public returns (uint []){
    var temp = fileLogs[msg.sender];


    uint[] memory ids = new uint[](transCounter);


    for (uint i=0; i<= transCounter; i++){
        ids[i]=temp[i].id;
    }

    return ids;
  }



  // constructor
    function TransManager() {
        creator = msg.sender;
    }

  // kills contract and sends remaining funds back to creator
   function kill() {
       if (msg.sender == creator) {
           selfdestruct(creator);
       }
   }

}
```

getTransactions - is always returning array of zeros. But I am expecting to return the indexed number.

```
truffle console --network ganache
truffle(ganache)> TransManager.deployed().then(function(instance){app=instance;})
undefined
truffle(ganache)> app.regTransaction("EDI","Hash",{from: web3.eth.accounts[1]})
{ tx: '0x46785333bce5f682c586ccf995682203a78d26bfba54957bb0bd5593d6cc4542',
  receipt: 
   { transactionHash: '0x46785333bce5f682c586ccf995682203a78d26bfba54957bb0bd5593d6cc4542',
     transactionIndex: 0,
     blockHash: '0x26bf163083f35bade4aca17c2d05706846b4dd8f555efa7117cdea0b64da51ca',
     blockNumber: 5,
     gasUsed: 146345,
     cumulativeGasUsed: 146345,
     contractAddress: null,
     logs: [],
     status: 1 },
  logs: [] }
truffle(ganache)> app.getTransactions()

Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:509:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:354:1)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:128:1)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/truffle-provider/wrapper.js:134:1
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:86:1
    at Object.InvalidResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:38:1)
```

Comment: Doesn't `getTransactions` always overflow? It seems to allocate space for only `transCounter` elements but then write `transCounter + 1` elements (due to the `i <= transCounter` condition).

Answer (score 0):

I think the only issue with your code is the terminal condition of the `for` loop. `i <= transCounter` should be `i < transCounter`. (Of course, `transCounter` is global, so this is only the right count as long as there's only one account using the contract, but that's an orthogonal issue.)

Here's a simplified, cleaned up version of your code that seems to work properly when testing in Remix:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract TransManager {
    uint transCounter;

    struct MetaData{
        uint id;
        address owner;
        string docType;
        string fileHash;
    }

    mapping (address => MetaData[])  fileLogs;

    function regTransaction(string _docType, string _fileHash) public {
        transCounter++;
        MetaData memory fileLog = MetaData(transCounter, msg.sender, _docType, _fileHash );

        fileLogs[msg.sender].push(fileLog);
    }

    function getTransactions() public view returns (uint[]) {
        MetaData[] storage temp = fileLogs[msg.sender];

        uint[] memory ids = new uint[](transCounter);

        for (uint i = 0; i < transCounter; i++){
            ids[i]=temp[i].id;
        }

        return ids;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks smarx. It is working in Remix when i invoke the function from truffle console i am getting below error . truffle(ganache)> app.getTransactions()
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode
    at Object.InvalidResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:41484:16)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:329530:36

Comment: If you can't debug it yourself, edit your question to include the code you're having trouble with.

Comment: It is the same code above which is working in Remix but not in truffle console.

Comment: I was referring to the Truffle code.

Comment: truffle console --network ganache
truffle(ganache)> TransManager.deployed().then(function(instance){app=instance;})
undefined
truffle(ganache)> app.regTransaction("EDI","Hash",{from: web3.eth.accounts[1]})

truffle(ganache)> app.getTransactions()
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode
     at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:509:1)
    at Object.InvalidResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:38:1)

Comment: Please edit your question to include this code. (It's easier to format there.) And also include your latest Solidity code. But my guess is just that the code you're deploying via Truffle doesn't match the code you're deploying with Remix.

Comment: Edit your question, not my answer. :-)