# Smart contract not working in truffle console but working in Remix IDE

Tags: contract-development, truffle, remix

```
    pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

    contract TransManager {
        uint transCounter;

        struct MetaData{
            uint id;
            address owner;
            string docType;
            string fileHash;
        }

        mapping (address => MetaData[])  fileLogs;

        function regTransaction(string _docType, string _fileHash) public {
            transCounter++;
            MetaData memory fileLog = MetaData(transCounter, msg.sender, _docType, _fileHash );

            fileLogs[msg.sender].push(fileLog);
        }

        function getTransactions() public view returns (uint[]) {
            MetaData[] storage temp = fileLogs[msg.sender];

            uint[] memory ids = new uint[](transCounter);

            for (uint i = 0; i < transCounter; i++){
                ids[i]=temp[i].id;
            }

            return ids;
        }
    }

truffle console --network ganache
truffle(ganache)> TransManager.deployed().then(function(instance){app=instance;})
undefined
truffle(ganache)> app.regTransaction("EDI","Hash",{from: web3.eth.accounts[1]})
{ tx: '0x46785333bce5f682c586ccf995682203a78d26bfba54957bb0bd5593d6cc4542',
  receipt: 
   { transactionHash: '0x46785333bce5f682c586ccf995682203a78d26bfba54957bb0bd5593d6cc4542',
     transactionIndex: 0,
     blockHash: '0x26bf163083f35bade4aca17c2d05706846b4dd8f555efa7117cdea0b64da51ca',
     blockNumber: 5,
     gasUsed: 146345,
     cumulativeGasUsed: 146345,
     contractAddress: null,
     logs: [],
     status: 1 },
  logs: [] }
truffle(ganache)> app.getTransactions()
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:509:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:354:1)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:128:1)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/truffle-provider/wrapper.js:134:1
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:86:1
    at Object.InvalidResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:38:1)
truffle(ganache)>
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want this:

```
app.getTransactions({from: web3.eth.accounts[1]});
```

I imagine the issue is a missing `msg.sender` or at the very least not the one that has the stored transactions.

Comment: There's no check to make sure temp.length == transCounter.

Comment: Yes, I pointed that out in my answer to OP's first question: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/42889/smart-contract-returning-values-as-zeros.